# Parent class's instance variable in Ruby

Tags: ruby, oop

So, for whatever reason there is no peek method in the ruby core Queue class.  I am trying to create a child class that implements the peek method.  However, I don't understand why I am getting an error. Is it not possible to use instance variables in this way?  Looking at the source code for Queue, there are instance variables in the constructor of the parent class. Is there a way to reference these in the subclass?

```
class PeekQueue < Queue
  def peek
    @mutex.synchronize{
      while true
        if @que.empty?
          raise ThreadError, "queue empty" if non_block
          @waiting.push Thread.current
          @mutex.sleep
        else
          return @que[0]
        end
      end
    }
  end
end

a = PeekQueue.new
a.push(1)
a.peek
NoMethodError: undefined method 'synchronize' for nil:NilClass
```

Edit: The Queue class is created at compile time, which is why I couldn't find the source on the ruby source code on github.  This is what the parent class looks like:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/574e20fea3a28663bfe2

Comment: I'm not familiar with the `Queue` class, but have you tried, `queue = Queue.new #=> #<Thread::Queue:0x007fe3e401c898>; 
enum = queue.to_enum #=> #<Enumerator: #<Thread::Queue:0x007fe3e401c898>:each>`? `next` and `peek` respond to enumerators, of course.

Comment: undefined method `each' for #<Thread::Queue:0x007f85f298d760>

Comment: Where are you defining @mutex? This seems to be nil

Comment: Where is the source code for Queue that you are looking at? On the ruby-doc site I'm seeing a C implementation that does not appear to define @mutex.

Comment: @jbeck the Queue class is generated at compile time. Here is a gist of what the Queue class looks like:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/072fceb97a75fae87988

Comment: If that is the `Queue` you're using, [it works](http://repl.it/bi1) without error. But as @jbeck notes, that is not what the MRI Core [`Queue` class](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Queue.html) looks like.

Comment: So, yes, you _can_ use an iVar defined in parent class, no problem. The problem is that iVars are often intended as undocumented private API. You can't count on it actually being there, and whether it is may be platform dependent. You're going to have to find a way to do what you need with Queue's public api, not iVars which are private.  It is true that some of ruby's stdlib stuff doesn't have the API's one would like.  If you need to write some weird code to do this, consider contributing to github concurrent-ruby, it doesn't currently contain any Queue enhancements, but could.

Comment: The folks at https://github.com/ruby-concurrency/concurrent-ruby are a friendly community of folks experienced with concurrency in ruby, they might have suggestions for best way to implement Queue#peek in a cross-platform way, and might be interested in including code in their gem to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see that error:

```
irb(main):025:0> qq = PeekQueue.new
=> #<PeekQueue:0x000006002bf498 @que=[], @num_waiting=0, @mutex=#<Mutex:0x000006002bf420>, @cond=#<ConditionVariable:0x000006002bf3f8 @waiters={}, @waiters_mutex=#<Mutex:0x000006002bf3a8>>>
irb(main):026:0> qq.peek
NameError: undefined local variable or method `non_block' for #<PeekQueue:0x000006002bf498>
        from (irb):15:in `block in peek'
        from (irb):12:in `synchronize'
        from (irb):12:in `peek'
        from (irb):26
        from /usr/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
irb(main):027:0> qq.push 1
=> #<ConditionVariable:0x000006002bf3f8 @waiters={}, @waiters_mutex=#<Mutex:0x000006002bf3a8>>
irb(main):028:0> qq.peek
=> 1
```

Method #non_block seems to be an issue. But access to @mutex works with your code.